# Accessing Elements in a Numpy Structured Array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a situation in which I would like to do the following:

```
import numpy as np
type1 = np.dtype([('col1', 'i'), ('col2', 'i')])
type2 = np.dtype([('cols', type1), ('info', 'S32')])
data = np.zeros(10, type2)

# The following doesn't work, but I want to do something similar
index = ['cols']['col1']
# Set column ['cols']['col1'] to 5
data[index] = 5

# I can only get this to work if I do the following: 
index = "['cols']['col1']"
eval('data' + index '= 5') # kinda scary
```

This doesn't work, but I found a workaround using the `exec` function but that feels pretty hacky. Does anyone have any suggestions how to programmatically create an index for nested structured numpy datatypes?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use `data['cols']['col1'] =5` ?

Comment: because I need to be able to define the indices in a separate step unfortunately.

Comment: What if you defined them like `index1, index2 = 'cols', 'col1'` and used `data[index1][index2]` ?

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
index = ['cols', 'col1']
data[index[0]][index[1]] = 5
```

**UPDATE**

This allows setting of values at any depths:

```
def set_deep(obj, names, value):
    if len(names) > 1:
        obj = obj[names[0]]
        if len(names) > 2:
            for name in names[1:-1]:
                obj = obj[name]
    obj[names[-1]] = value
```

Usage:

```
set_deep(data, ['cols', 'col1'], 5)

set_deep(data, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 5)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is close to what I might end up having to use, but have structured datatypes that are not just 2 deep. I might have things defined like `data['a']['b']['c']['d']`. In this case I guess I could do a for loop or something.

Comment: I think this might be as close as we can get without using the `exec` statement.